# Sitecore ECM module How to manage the localization for a newsletter

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

I m building a newsletter via the ECM module which should be sent in french or dutch.

I would like to understand how it will work for the newsletter. (I have found a lot of information for a CMS Web Site but nothing)

That's my understanding:

The editor will write the article in french. He will create a new version for French.
The translator will have to create a new version for Dutch and translate the text.

-> We have got two versions.

Will there be any issue during the build of the newsletter by the administrator ?

And when we will send the newsletter, how is that working ?

Is the language coming from a property (User Definition) ? 
Is the french client will receive the newsletter in french and the Dutch client will receive in Dutch ?

Thank you,

Comment: for the newsletter, I will need to create a new handler type for the event name="subscriber:assigned". In the source code, i will have to define a MailMessageItem object and assigned the language defined in the user property to that object. If you need more information regarding the localization for a newsletter, don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A message is a Sitecore item (or item tree). The ECM user will create a message item in two versions (French and Dutch) and fill the content.

ECM (1.0 - 1.3.3) out of the box can send a message in one language only. The language to send is chosen by ECM user when he starts a dispatch.

At the same time it is possible to customize ECM to choose a certain message language for each resipient.

The `subscriber:assigned` event is a good option when you need to modify the content of the message before sending to a recipient. This event is defined in the `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.config` file.

See code example:

```
public void OnSubscriberAssigned(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  MailMessageItem message = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as MailMessageItem;

  // Contact represents a recipient
  Contact recipient = message.PersonalizationContact;

  message.TargetLanguage = GetLanguageYouWantForRecipient(recipient);
}
```